# How can i get file object with S3 Bucket using Bucket URL

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi i want to get object of aws s3 Bucket using Url with javascript . what i am trying is

```
   function getUrlFromBucket(s3Bucket,fileName){
   const {config :{params,region}} = s3Bucket;
   const regionString = region.includes('us-east-1') ?'':('-' + region)
```

which  is not helping me .Any Help ?